# How to open files at a Interval of some of number

Tags: javascript, function, loops, jsx, photoshop-script

I have a folder in which there are some files and i want to open those files in Photoshop but not at once . Let say there are more than 20 files in a folder so i want to open 20 files at once and do something with those files and then remaining files will open and again do something with those files.
I'm making a script for Photoshop using JavaScript so please help me... thank you

Comment: Your question is *too broad* as you havent shown any code and you havent described an exact problem. Instead of voting for that, I decided to add some dupes that might help you along the way. Have fun coding :)

Comment: FYI, to my knowledge this is not possible with scripting, you'll need a CEP panel for this (in Photoshop JS all commands are blocking and there're no setInterval/setTimout)